# Can a Java selenium project be added and run on Azure

Tags: java, azure, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a java selenium project and I am looking to deploy this onto azure. Can this be done?

Comment: if you give some insights about the project then it could be helpful.

Comment: What Azure service you are talking about? Azure VM, Could Service or App Service?